# save hidden values in header after redirect

Tags: hidden, postdata

I have a form with 2 pages that retrieve information, that information is stored in my header file as hidden values.  After the second page the user is directed to a third party payment system.  Then they are redirected back to the third page of the form.  However, my header does not have the hidden values anymore.  how do i gain access to those values, as i do nee them for database purposes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the third party payment system you speak of is PayPal, there's a way to set values that they'll send back to you.

However, if the payment system does not have such an API, then I think you're out of luck.  It would be their system that generates the headers that would come back to you. It's highly unlikely that their API wouldn't have a way to do it though.

Comment: it isnt paypal, but the method you explained is implemented, thanks